# Django not showing updated css files

Tags: django, caching

So I'm using sass to update my Django site and I am using git to version the whole thing. I recently made an update to CSS file that had some bad errors in it. Sass compiled the changes and I pushed the new version to the server. I have looked on the server and the new css file is in fact there and reflects the changes, however when I look at our site the css file is being referenced as a cached file:

"/static/CACHE/css/35ed7f45f0e3.css"

Unfortunatley this cached version still has the errors in it, how can I tell django and memcache to refresh this reference so my site doesn't look like poop?

I have tried clearing the cache via the shell but the old cached file reference persists in my html.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you run collectstatic ?

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Comment: Yep, this was it, as soon as I read your comment I groaned out loud. The dev that trained my actually made a point of explaining this to me as if he knew I would screw this up someday. Thank you much Adrien!

Comment: I get the next `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path`. It means that `collecstatic` is a plugin and I am not using it?

Answer (score 0):

**2020**

If `python manage.py collectstatic` solution doesn't work and everything is correct in your code.
Press `ctr + F5` in your browser to bypass the cache.

Then it will work hopefully.